# Completely backup bluetooth pairings/profiles

Tags: windows-8, backup, bluetooth

I have a device running Windows 8 embedded using an Intel wireless Bluetooth 4.0 + hs adapter. Every few weeks/months the device needs to be wiped to upgrade the software.

In what way can I completely back up the Bluetooth pairings/profiles/settings so that there is no interruption in Bluetooth connectivity after the wipe occurs?

I have been trying to search for this and have found little information. The information I have found references `HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet\Enum\BTH` and `BTHENUM`.

Is backing up these two registry files enough to maintain the information or are there other registry entries or files/folders on the system that would be necessary to maintain this information?

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth pairings are stored at

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys`

The latter is accessible only by the SYSTEM user. So you you'll need to run regedit using e.g. [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) (from an elevated command prompt): `psexec64 -i -s regedit`

Reboot the system after restoring these keys for the changes to take effect.

---

Note also that it is generally impossible to port Bluetooth pairings from one PC to another as pairings depend on the bluetooth adapter's MAC address, which is often hardcoded and cannot be changed.